# What type of 5¼" drive bays does the Thermaltake W200 case feature?

Tags: case

I'm currently looking for an "old-school" server tower case with numerous external 5¼" bays, which are often populated with hot-swap HDD cages with backplanes, so I recently stumbled upon [Thermaltake's Core W200 chassis.](https://www.thermaltake.com/core-w200.html) What does puzzle me, however, is that the datasheet states that there are 3 external 5¼" bays, yet according to the product photos, there must be more than three of them (or at least two of them are double-height ones):

[image: Case front with external bays]
[image: Case front with hot-swap HDD cages]

As far as my eyesight is good enough, there are two single-height bays + one double-height one + one triple-height one, which totals an equivalent of **seven single-height 5 ¼" bays.** So, who's right now?

Comment: Those are removable bays alright, question is what devices they support?

Comment: Watch a review on youtube. Much more reliable than photos on the manufacturers website

Comment: That's the crux: I'd like to construct a 5¼" cage supporting five Antmicro Scalenode boards each to make a computing cluster.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vMi5qKHf8LA

Comment: I often look at the Amazon reviews with the least stars to see what kind of downsides I can expect https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01EGBZA1C#customerReviews

Comment: "*two of them are double-height ones*" -- You have it backwards.  The predominant 5.25" form-factor is officially called half-height.  What you're (incorrectly )calling "*double-height*" is actually the old full-height of 3.25", the height of the [Seagate ST506](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1399647/Seagate-St506.html?page=9), the first 5.25" HDD.

Comment: Yes, @sawdust! Theoretically you are absolutely right, yet there are not many "old full-height" (nowadays: double-height) devices left (LTO tape drives, for instance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into the [instruction video](https://youtu.be/vMi5qKHf8LA?t=305) (谢谢你, Moab!), it turned out that there are many more than three 5¼" openings:

[image: front view with front panel removed]

The only issue are the drive bays themselves: Apparently, only three of them come with the case, but I've heard you can buy them as spare parts.

Comment: Where can you get these spare parts from? I've looked around and cannot seem to find any.

Comment: 5¼" drive bays are pretty standard, so you've got a good chance to find spare ones.

Comment: I've found the 5¼" brackets on the US Thermaltake webshop, they do not ship to Europe as far as I can see. It's a bit odd that these parts are so difficult to source. The 3½" drive bays (from the manual) are nowhere to be found - I am of course talking about Thermaltakes original parts here, not thirdparty. Thermaltake has not replied to my email either.

Comment: AFAIK, Galaxus distributes the brackets in Europe, too.

Comment: I've asked some of the biggest importers about this, also tried four different emails to Thermaltake support and sales - to no avail. Galaxus doesn't have them. Nothing here seems to be easy to get hold of.